# Restrict RAM usage of Chrome or executables in general?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, restrictions, memory-limit

I need a way to enforce hard limits on RAM usage for specific EXEs, since Chrome is leaking memory all the time and crashing my system.
Is it possible to simply disable the Large Address Aware flag of the 32bit version?

Comment: Is the latest version of Chrome installed, it should not do this.

Comment: Yes, I suspect the problem is the extension I am using. I am not looking for ways to optimize Chrome, though. I know about different tab suspenders etc. This will not solve my problem, I want to enforce a hard limit that simply cannot be broken by any executable even if the exectuble itself will crash. This is about avoiding a complete system crash.